# Display of zoomable image thumbnails instead of symbols on maps

Tags: qgis, shapefile

sincere congratulations on your ingenous QGIS and the many extremely useful extensions. In my research on African archaeology I work a lot with geotagged pictures (drawings; photos; plates etc.) which are elements of self-defined GIS data records and which I display on my own maps, satellite imagery and the like using photo2shape. Now, what I am really dreaming of is to be able to look at preview thumbnails (that can be opened in larger size by a click) instead of symbols on my maps, such as it is possible, for instance, in ArcGIS or GoogleEarth.

Is this already possible in QGIS? Or would someone develop it perhaps? This feature would be extremely useful for all sorts of research and other applications.

Comment: You may be better off asking this question on the QGIS mailing list. - http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user

Comment: Hi GIS-Jonathan. Recently QGIS closed its forum and has [shifted some of its Q-n-A over to gis.stackexchange](http://www.qgis.org/en/community.html). You will probably see more users of QGIS showing up with questions that, in the past, may have seemed more appropriate to ask to the lists.

Comment: There is already one plugin idea in the qgis plugin wish list for a magnifier http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Python_Plugin_Ideas Maybe this is what you mean with Preview. Now somebody just has to spend some of his time for coding

Comment: Or do you mean something like this? http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/GetStart_Ex1_6.htm

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility might be to put your geotagged photos inside a HTML annotation. 
Nathan demonstrated this feature on his [blog](http://nathanw.net/2012/09/04/five-new-awesomely-awesome-qgis-features/).

Maybe you could write a python script, which converts the coordinates inside your geotagged pictures into a point layer and afterwards assigns a html-annotation containing a thumbnail with your image (and a link to the original) to each of the created points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I would take a look at the [eVis plugin](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/evis/).  From their website:

> "eVis has primarily been developed to easily view geocoded photos
>   associated by attributes to features in the QGIS mapping environment"